# Possible to apply ETL and linking processes to a variable collection of files in a Sharepoint folder?

Tags: excel, etl, powerquery, organization

Every month I have to manually export 40+ reports (excel files generally) into a SharePoint folder. I want to create a power query in Excel to link all the reports (based on a common field in all reports) and include only 2-3 columns of data from each report.

How can I use ETL in Power Query to create queries that can apply to new reports each month, without having to redo the queries each month for the new reports?

Comment: Are the file names the same each month? Do the number of files change each month?

Comment: The file names do not change (because I have to manually name them after I export them). The number of files sometimes changes based on if I am doing a monthly, quarterly, or fiscal year analysis. But, I planned to create a separate workbook with queries for monthly, quarterly and FY - so in that case, No, the number of files would not change.

Comment: Not sure that being on Sharepoint impacts things, but if file names don't change then whatever process you set up in the first month should be able to refreshed on future months. What have you tested that makes this not true?

Comment: Can you restate your question more generally? E.g. - "Possible to apply ETL and linking processes to a variable collection of files in a Sharepoint folder?" - (which is what I think you're asking - and the answer is "of course, easily").

Comment: @horseyride2 I'll admit, I'm sure there's a simple part of this equation that I don't quite grasp yet. However, to clarify, I can't refresh the 40+ reports every month because I have to export each file individually and manually - meaning that I have to visit a website (Power BI, Medallia, Pyramid), open the desired report, select specific parameters from the dropdowns, export the report, and save a new copy of each report every month.

Comment: @horseyride2 Eventually I want to be able to set up a process to import the files and be able to refresh them so that I can easily run the monthly query on the refreshed reports. But, that is going to take a long time to understand where the original source data is stored and set up a query to import each report (it's a very complex system of data beyond the scope of my knowledge). So, essentially, every month I have an entirely new workbook full of worksheets with the current month's reports. How can I apply the queries I created to every month's new workbook of reports?

Comment: @AndreyYakimov, That's a much better way to word the question. I edited it for clarity as you suggested. Perhaps you can see my two comments above and provide further insights. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, now the question makes sense, but your detail is too specific to be helpful. So, are you saying you'd like to apply same transform (pick out 2-3 columns) to a list of files in a sharepoint folder, and then build a table with columns donated by each file, linked by IDs shared among files? A general, short, and simple example of the sources-transforms-output would help.

Comment: To give you an example - I have no idea what Medalia or Pyramid do, and it's not important to the question - so don't include that. I can, however, picture 40+/-5 files in a SharePoint folder, hopefully all in CSV format, that I need to link into a table based on a common field. Feel free to clean up your comments, too! :) I'll clean up mine, and we can get a good how-to going. That is an interesting non-trivial PQ ETL application case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250356/discussion-between-andrey-yakimov-and-whatdata).

Comment: @Mupppet Bear, I've been away for the holidays and would love to chat to continue this conversation!